# PHP WebDAV server unable to perform PUT method using Windows

Tags: php, windows-7, webdav

I'm trying to implement a PHP-based WebDAV server to be able to use it under OS Windows (more precisely Windows 7).

Everything works just fine, except for the PUT method. When I try to upload a file from the filesystem to the WebDAV server the request content-lenght is empty, meaning i can't read the file i want to put in the server.

Here is what I'm receiveng when I drag a file (simple .txt file) using Windows:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601
[HTTP_TRANSLATE] => f
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 0
[HTTP_VIA] => 1.1 squid.Sole:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9), 1.0 squidcache.Proxy6.CCSP:3129 (squid/2.6.STABLE24)
[PATH] => /bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
[REQUEST_METHOD] => PUT
```

Uploading the same file using a dedicated webdav client, i get a valid response and the file is being uploaded. Here is what I get using CyberDuck client:

```
[HTTP_EXPECT] => 100-continue
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 263
[CONTENT_TYPE] => text/plain
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Cyberduck/4.2.1 (9350) (Windows 7/6.1) (x86)
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate
[PATH] => /bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => PUT
```

The CONTENT-LENGTH field changed and the file is online on the server as i should be.
I will post my code fragment here:

```
$options = Array();
$options["path"] = $this->path;
$options["content_length"] = $_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];
$options["stream"] = fopen('php://input', 'r');

$stat = $this->PUT($options); // In the PUT method I fopen the destination file in "w"

if ($stat === false) {
    $stat = "403 Forbidden";
} else if (is_resource($stat) && get_resource_type($stat) == "stream") {
    $stream = $stat;

    $stat = $options["new"] ? "201 Created" : "204 No Content";
    if (!empty($options["ranges"])) {
        if (0 == fseek($stream, $range[0]["start"], SEEK_SET)) {
            $length = $range[0]["end"]-$range[0]["start"]+1;
            if (!fwrite($stream, fread($options["stream"], $length))) {
                 $stat = "403 Forbidden"; 
            }
        } else {
            $stat = "403 Forbidden"; 
        }
    }else {
        while (!feof($options["stream"])) {
            if (false === fwrite($stream, fread($options["stream"], 4096))) { //The fread reads nothing from the stream...
                $stat = "403 Forbidden"; 
                break;
            }
         }
      }
    fclose($stream);    
}
```

What could I do to solve this issue? is there any thing to set in Windows to make it work or is it just my code who lacks something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will first create a 0-byte file. After this succeeds it will upload the entire file.

Comment: Following your lead, I was able to make the server succeed on the first PUT. This is followed by a PROPFIND and then comes the second PUT. Only, its content:length is empty as well. I cannot figure out why and how to make it work...

Comment: I'm the author of this project: http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/ This project should work. I would recommend trying that and see what windows is sending back and forth and try to reverse engineer. I've got several years of fixing odd bugs with various clients in there ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I tried SabreDAV in the past, having the same issue along with others. The second PUT comes with a content_length = 0 under windows client. All the other clients i tried (I tried 5) work and the content_length is equal to the file size.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I solved it. Windows WebClient (or at least Windows7 one) prevents file PUT when locking isn't disabled.
For those who have the same issue, just open regedit.exe and go to and in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WebClient\Parameters" disable SupportLocking (value must be 0). This way, the first PUT will result empty (CONTENT_LENGTH = 0), but the second one will have the filesize of the file you are uploading on the server.